# Set visibility to View.INVISIBLE doesn't work while startAnimation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

For a simple Android app, we could easily set the text view show or hide by `tv.visibility = View.VISIBLE`.

However, when I add animation for the text, like `tv.startAnimation(animation)`, the button doesn't work any more.

Just wondering if anything that I had missed?

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val tv: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
        val btn: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)

        val animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this@MainActivity, R.anim.slide_up)
        tv.startAnimation(animation) // comment this line to make the button work

        btn.setOnClickListener {
            if (tv.visibility == View.INVISIBLE) {
                tv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                tv.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean when you added `startAnimation()`,and `btn` is not clickable? or `tv` is not invisible  and `btn` work?

Comment: @liveAnyway Thanks for your comment. `tv` is not invisible and `btn` could be clicked

Comment: I tested your code. and worked well. If your `R.anim.slide_up` is right? I tried 'android.R.anim.ANY_ANIM' and worked well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for being late.

try this:

```
        btn.setOnClickListener {
            if (tv.visibility == View.INVISIBLE) {
                tv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                tv.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                tv.clearAnimation() // add this
            }
        }
```